# How to fetch records from DB2 for the last 7 days (1 WEEK) from today

Tags: sql, database, db2, where-clause

I am using DB2. I want to fetch records for this week from a column. I want to use similar to below (This is for SQL 2005)

```
Select count(*) from Applications WHERE ReceivedDate is this week. (Last 7 days including today)
```

Comment: If you (only) use DB2 don't tag MySQL. I removed it for you.

Comment: @stickybit: Thank you buddy, any answer for the question asked you know?

Comment: It's [`WEEK`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000871.html?pos=2), not `YEARWEEK`. Where did you get that from? And there's no `CURDATE()` function in Db2 either.

Comment: @mustaccio: Mate that query I wrote is for SQL 2005. I want to achieve the same in DB2 mate Any pointers or equivalent query you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE ReceivedDate > current date - 7 days
```